# Site layout splitted into rows and columns - alignment problem

Tags: css

I would like to create a layout that will split my page into rows and modules.

Row is just a whole width flex div that contains other elements which I call modules, like in the picture below:

[image]

As you can also see, when I have one column, content is centered - but it's not the rule. But I want to be able to center the content (it may be anything).

When I have two columns, the left one should be right-aligned and the right one should be left aligned. With some margin "in the center".

The problem is that, when I was playing with css sandbox, it looks like I got what I wanted. But, when I move it to my project, it doesn't work. Mainly the left column is not right aligned as it should be. What's wrong?

Oh, of course everything should be responsive :)

```css
:root {
--default-padding: 20px;
--default-margin: 20px;
--double-margin: calc(var(--default-margin) * 2);
--double-padding: calc(var(--default-padding) * 2);
}

.row {
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: top;
    width: 100%
  }

.row > div {
   flex-grow: 1;
   width: 0px;
   min-width: 200px; /* it makes flex responsive */
}

.row > div:first-child > * {
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: var(--default-margin);
   text-align: right;
}

.row > div:last-child > * {
   margin-left: var(--default-margin);
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto; /* responsive image */
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div>
        <h1 style="text-align: center">Centered content</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div>
        <img src="img.jpg" id="main_img"/>
    </div>

    <div>
      <p>
        <h1>Some header</h1>
        <ul>
          <li>list item</li>
          <li>list item</li>
        </ul>
      </p>
      <button class="cta module-right">ZAMÓW TERAZ</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, what's wrong with this code? (these are my beginnings in css, I am mostly desktop and backend programmer)

Comment: see https://jsfiddle.net/6gv0473u/ (removed styles in `.row > div`, used `justify-content: space-between`, changed `<p>` to `<div>`) - you can inspect element to check why so

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is by `display: flex;`. If you are not familiar with it I would recommend you to learn about it from here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ since it would make it a lot easier for you. I have done a sample code of what you want to achieve using flex. Hope this helps

HTML

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center">
  <h1>Centered content</h1>
</div>

<div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center">

  <div class="img-box">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
  </div>

  <div class="flex-column">
    <div>
      <h1 class="no-margin">Some header</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>list item</li>
        <li>list item</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button>ZAMÓW TERAZ</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.d-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-row {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-column {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.justify-content-center {
  justify-content: center;
}

.img-box {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.no-margin {
  margin: 0;
}
```

JS Fiddle Link : https://jsfiddle.net/SJ_KIllshot/gh6d5uzy/1/